# How do I get PyTesseract OCR to recognise characters when there is a line on top of the chars

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

So I'm trying to write a program that will read in numbers of the graph (and then do stuff but that's irrelevant). I've got the following code, which works mostly.

```
img_resource_path = resource_path(img_path)
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = PATH_TO_TESSERACT
img = cv2.imread(img_resource_path, 0)
kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)
thresh = 255 - cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
x,y,w,h = 0, 615, 680, 200  
ROI = thresh[y:y+h,x:x+w]
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(ROI, lang='eng')
```

The issue is that there is a black line on top of some of the lines of the table, which makes Tesseract read the characters incorrectly. It should output -90.58dB but it outputs -950.58dB.

How do I make it so it ignores the black line on top? (Picture attached with what it looks like)

Edit: Can I create my own training data and use that. A few online sources including the Tesseract docs said that likely retraining will not help. Any opinions?

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ1zx.png)

Comment: In this particular image, the gridlines appear to be gray. Probably you can get rid of the gridlines with simple thresholding operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with **easyocr**. It using tesseract engine for OCR operation. install easyocr by `pip install easyocr`

```
import easyocr
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'], gpu=False)
result = reader.readtext('3.png')
for detection in result:
    print(detection)
```

output is,

```
([[8, 8], [458, 8], [458, 88], [8, 88]], '-90.58 dB', 0.7896991366270714)
([[7, 84], [460, 84], [460, 168], [7, 168]], '-90.58 dB', 0.7465829283820857)
```

Comment: Thanks! Did some testing and looks to be working. I did find a much much easier way to extract the data I need from a csv file instead of trying to OCR an image. But think I have another use for this. Thanks

Comment: Does easyocr still require the tesseract engine at all?

Comment: No.. You don't need that.. Just install the library and feel free to use.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to use it now. But I am getting this Error: "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2588' in position 12: character maps to <undefined>"
From googling, it seems to be because its not utf-8? All the solutions online are for using open() and other methods. Is there a way to fix this with the code you gave me?

Comment: which line it fails?.. can you specify the line number?... whether it fails during library installation?

Comment: if you using linux or ubuntu os.. **export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8** in terminal and run the program. if windows , try this **set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8** after activating your environment in terminal

Comment: I believe I fixed it. It seems I had a slightly older version of numpy and/or pytorch, which was messing with easyocr